# Cant divide long int objects

Tags: python, pandas, long-integer

I have a column with large weights. So large, I cant convert it to integers:

```
df.wtfinl.astype(int)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Well, I ignore this, and still try to create relative weights:

```
df['nobsSum'] = df.groupby(df.index)['wtfinl'].sum()
df['nobsRel'] = df['wtfinl'] / df['nobsSum']
```

However, that appears not to be supported (see error in the end). Ultimatively, I want to create weighted statistics:

```
for col in cols:
    df[col] = dfJFROut[col] * df['nobsRel']
df.groupby(level=list(range(len(timeIndex) + 1 ))).sum()[cols + ['nobsRel']]
```

(this used  to work, when I wasnt using high precision for `wtfinl`. The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 652, in na_op
    raise_on_error=True, **eval_kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/computation/expressions.py", line 210, in evaluate
    **eval_kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/computation/expressions.py", line 63, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 676, in safe_na_op
    return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 658, in na_op
    result[mask] = op(x[mask], _values_from_object(y[mask]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-147-9c334d96d5fb>", line 1, in <module>
    dfJFROut['wtfinl'] / dfJFROut['nobsSum']
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 715, in wrapper
    result = wrap_results(safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues))
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 686, in safe_na_op
    lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
  File "pandas/src/algos_common_helper.pxi", line 1176, in pandas.algos.arrmap_object (pandas/algos.c:45858)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 686, in <lambda>
    lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

So why does it say `str` when it's a long int? Just so you're sure that I'm really dividing numbers:

```
df.iloc[0][['wtfinl', 'nobsSum']]
Out[152]: 

wtfinl                                    301609551731007744
nobsSum    3016095517310077444494228807945226498723699710...
Name: (2000, 30), dtype: object

df.iloc[0]['wtfinl'] / dfJFROut.iloc[0]['nobsSum']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-149-072b4e43bbc3>", line 1, in <module>
    dfJFROut.iloc[0]['wtfinl'] / dfJFROut.iloc[0]['nobsSum']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: `dtype: object` - says it's a string. BTW,  `np.iinfo(np.int64)` - will show you limits for `np.int64` dtype, which AFAIK is  the maximum integer you can have in Pandas / NumPy

Comment: @MaxU I am aware that it's an object. The question is how to compute my weighted statistics, when I'm not allowed to divide by long int..

Comment: @FooBar, You could leverage the use of `np.float64` dtype with precision=0, to compute the weighted stats for long ints. And regarding the *TypeError*, I feel it's because they are not converted to integers(although you've typecasted it) but are rather string objects and dividing them is certainly not possible. Importing something like `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.f' % x)` at the beginning would eliminate such issues.